# Canvas wont display image inside of it

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="spriteCanvas" width="500" height="500">
        <img id="coin" width="440" height="40" src="coin.png">
    </canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried placing an image inside a canvas element, but it won't display on the browser. I know the image tag works because it's displayed if I place it outside of the canvas element. Also, if I inspect the canvas element, I can see that the image is inside, but its dimensions are 0 by 0. Can somebody explain why this isn't working?

EDIT: My original code added the image through javascript, but it wouldn't show on the canvas. It was giving me the same problems as above. But I just realized I was missing "onload".

original code:

```
var coinImage = new Image();
coinImage.src = "coin.png";
var sCanvas = document.getElementById('spriteCanvas');

function Sprite(canvas, width, height, image){
  this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.image = image;
}

Sprite.prototype.render = function() {
  var that = this;
  this.context.drawImage(that.image, 0, 0);
}

function init() {
  var coin = new Sprite(sCanvas, 100, 100, coinImage);
  coin.render();
}

init();
```

editted code:

```
var coinImage = new Image();
coinImage.src = "coin.png";
var sCanvas = document.getElementById('spriteCanvas');

function Sprite(canvas, width, height, image){
    this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.image = image;
}

Sprite.prototype.render = function() {
    var that = this;
    this.context.drawImage(that.image, 0, 0);
}

coinImage.onload = function () {
    var coin = new Sprite(sCanvas, 100, 100, coinImage);
    coin.render();
}
```

Comment: Please lookup how to use the `<canvas>` tag, that isn't how it works. You draw on the canvas, not place HTML elements inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't how a `<canvas>` tag works.  If you want your image to appear in your canvas, you will have to use JavaScript to place the pixels of the image into your canvas.

`<canvas>`s are exactly what they state: canvases.  They are an element for you to draw on programmatically.  If you just want to display an image on a page, you don't need a canvas, you just need the `<img>` tag.  In fact, elements should not be placed in `<canvas>`.

Take a look at [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) and this tutorial: [HTML5 Canvas Image Tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/).

And this snippet:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("painting"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 30, 50);
};

image.src = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=10a9e8743fb0";
```

```html
<canvas id="painting" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

To draw an image on a canvas, use the following method:

```
drawImage(image,x,y)
```

If the image you want to draw is not in the DOM already you can load an image directly from a URL with a few lines of javascript.

```
function loadAndDrawImage(url)
{
    // Create an image object. This is not attached to the DOM and is not part of the page.
    var image = new Image();

    // When the image has loaded, draw it to the canvas
    image.onload = function()
    {
        // draw image...
    }

    // Now set the source of the image that we want to load
    image.src = url;
}
loadAndDrawImage("http://www---.png");
```